# Substract 2 dates from input datetime

Tags: javascript, vue.js, date

I'm collecting 2 dates from inputs and I'd like to display the difference (in hours and minutes) of those two dates. But when I try to get the difference, it returns NaN.
Does anyone know how to transform a getElementById value into a substractable (not sure it's a word) number ?

```
<div class="form">
  <input type="text" value="Heure début" />
  <input type="datetime-local" id="begin-time" name="meeting-time" value="" min="2018-06-07T00:00"
            max="2022-06-14T00:00"><br />
  <input type="text" value="Heure fin" />
  <input type="datetime-local" id="end-time" name="meeting-time" value="" min="2018-06-07T00:00"
            max="2022-06-14T00:00"><br />
  <p id="difference"></p>
  <v-btn @click="differenceTime()">VALIDER</v-btn>
</div>
```

I want to substract the end-time with the begin-time and then display the difference in the p (id=difference).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```js
function differenceTime() {
  $('#difference').text( parseFloat( (Date.parse( $( '#end-time' ).val() ) - Date.parse( $( '#begin-time' ).val() ) )/(1000*60*60) ).toFixed(2) + ' Hours');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
  <input type="text" value="Heure début" />
  <input type="datetime-local" id="begin-time" name="meeting-time" value="" min="2018-06-07T00:00"
            max="2022-06-14T00:00"><br />
  <input type="text" value="Heure fin" />
  <input type="datetime-local" id="end-time" name="meeting-time" value="" min="2018-06-07T00:00"
            max="2022-06-14T00:00"><br />
  <p id="difference"></p>
  <button onClick="differenceTime()">VALIDER</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your inputs should be getting their values from your component props or data. Not sure what version of Vue you are using.

Also you should refrain from accessing the DOM directly when using a framework like Vue.